# Using subfloat to place figures side by side

Tags: subfloats, document-classes

Hi am using the following code to place two figures side by side:

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

%other part of code which compiles fine

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics{<figure1>}\label{<figure1>}}
     \subfloat[][b]{\includegraphics{<figure2>}\label{<figure2>}}
     \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a) x method (b) y method}
     \label{steady_state}
\end{figure}

%remaining part
```

this gives me an error: `\subfloat` outside float.

what would be incorrect in this ??

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 21):

Please *always* post a complete document that shows the error. If I make a document from your posted fragments then I get no error, so presumably your error is in a part of your document you have not shown.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
other part of code which compiles fine

\begin{figure}
     \centering
     \subfloat[][a]{\includegraphics{<figure1>}\label{<figure1>}}
     \subfloat[][b]{\includegraphics{<figure2>}\label{<figure2>}}
     \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a) x method (b) y method}
     \label{steady_state}
\end{figure}
%remaining part

\end{document}
```

If you can reproduce the error please edit your question to include a document that shows the problem.

Comment: i am actually using a special documentclass called 'aipproc'. This is prescribed for any publication by the American Institute of Physics, available at http://www.cec-icmc.org/author-information/publication/forms/ . I am very new to LaTex typsetting and so wasn't unsure where the problem could be. Is there a way to find out if some settings in the 'aipproc' class prohibits placing figures side by side ? Thanks David :)

Comment: i am actually using a special documentclass called 'aipproc'. This is prescribed for any publication under the American Institute of Physics banner, and is available at http://www.cec-icmc.org/author-information/publication/forms/ . I am very new to LaTex typsetting and so was unsure where the problem could be. Is there a way to find out if some settings in the 'aipproc' class prohibits placing figures side by side ? Thanks David :)

Comment: sorry no time to download that now but if subfgloat doesn;t work you can always put the images side by side under a single caption just `\includegraphics{...}\hspace{10pt}\includegraphics{....} \caption{...}`

Comment: Where would you put the source reference in case of using subfloat images: One single source below each image or just one source into the main caption?

Comment: @Dave that's a design question not a tex one, just do whatever is the convention in your field or the journal you  are publishing in.

Answer (score 3):

[You mention you are using the `aipproc` document class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111822/using-subfloat-to-place-figures-side-by-side/330562#comment249878_111824)... the more recent version of this is `aip-cp`.

The [`aip-cp` document class](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors) - for AIP Conference Proceedings - doesn't support using `\subfloat`. Moreover, it's best to avoid using additional packages for conference proceedings or journal submissions when you don't have to. Especially with subfigures when you can place them in other structures without problem.

Below I've placed each subfigure inside a `tabular` that is aligned at the `[b]`aseline using the following default layout per subfigure:

```
\begin{tabular}[b]{c}
  <subfigure image> \\
  \small <subfigure caption>
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{aip-cp}% http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/proceeding/aipcp/info/authors

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

Some text here.

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{example-image-a} \\
    \small (a)
  \end{tabular} \qquad
  \begin{tabular}[b]{c}
    \includegraphics[width=.25\linewidth]{example-image-b} \\
    \small (b)
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{Comparison of steady state results (a)~x method (b)~y method}
\end{figure}

Some more text here.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this structure. You must use these packages

```
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{figure}
\centering
  % Requires \usepackage{graphicx}
  \subfloat[caption fig (a).]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{<fig1>}\label{fig1}}
  \hspace{0.5cm}
  \subfloat[caption fig b.]{\includegraphics[width=7cm]{<fig2>}\label{fig2}}
  \vspace{0.5cm}
   \caption{caption fig.}\label{fig:}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You actually repeated OP question and not solve his/her problem.