# Mixed size sub-figures in LyX without ERT ("evil red text")

Tags: floats, formatting, lyx, subfloats

Is there a way in LyX to make [this figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/87976/14527), with its three sub-figures having the same arrangement as in that answer, but without resorting to using actual LaTeX code?

I found an almost duplicate question, where the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327697/14527) also used LaTeX code instead of  the LyX GUI (graphical user interface).

Comment: If you want to do the height measuring I'm pretty sure you have to use ERTs.

Comment: What if I just want subfig (a) on the left, and subfigs (b) and (c) on the right, taking up the same amount of space? It's so easy to do in Microsoft Word or Libre Office Writer, isn't LyX supposed to make it like that for the user, and then generate the TeX itself?

Comment: Add two minipages of the same width (Insert -> Box -> Frameless) inside a figure,  and add subfigures inside each of the minipages by doing Insert -> Figure again with the cursor inside them.

Comment: WOW! Let me try it !! I was unaware of the existence of "mini-pages"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert a `minipage` environment with Insert -> Box -> Frameless. To insert a subfloat you do Insert -> Float -> Figure inside an existing figure float. To make a similar arrangement to what you're asking, the basic steps are:

1. Insert -> Float -> Figure.
2. Move cursor to before the caption of this figure, and add a `minipage` with Insert -> Box -> Frameless.
3. Open the settings of the minipage by right clicking the header or title, or whatever you want to call it, of the minipage (where it says *Box (Minipage)* and selecting *Settings*.

   1. Set the width to for example 47% of the Column width (or Line width). (If you don't want any space between the minipages, you can use 50%.)
   2. For the alignment, set the *vertical* alignment of the *Box* to *Bottom*. Close the settings.
4. With the cursor inside the minipage, use Insert -> Float -> Figure (or the button on the toolbar) to insert a subfloat.
5. Move the cursor outside the minipage. Don't make a new line, just have the cursor just to the right of it.
6. If you made the minipage <50%, do Insert -> Formatting -> Horizontal Space, and choose *Horizontal filling* for the space.
7. Add a second minipage as in step 2 and 3.
8. Inside this minipage, add two subfloats with a paragraph break (hit enter) between them.

Depending on the size of the images, you may want to horizontally center them, which you do in the usual way, by adjusting the paragraph settings inside each subfloat.

Note I did this in an old version of LyX, I can't guarantee that it's identical in the latest one. This is what it looks like here, with `\rule{<width>}{<height>}` instead of images.

[image]

Comment: It's an elegant solution. Maybe the TeX generated from this LyX file will be simpler than the huge mess of TeX code used in the answers to the original questions.